# has_and_belongs_to_many creating duplicate entries in model

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have three tables **Issues**, **Labels**, & **IssuesLabel**

**issues.rb**

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :labels
end
```

**labels.rb**

```
class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :issues
end
```

**issues_label.rb**

```
class IssuesLabel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issue
  belongs_to :label
end
```

When I call `issue.labels.find_or_create_by(name: 'bug')` for one issue,
and `issue.labels.find_or_create_by(name: 'bug')` for a different issue, it creates two different records in the `Labels` table for `bug`

I'm expecting it to find the existing `bug` record and add an entry to the `IssuesLabel` join table. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note, that has_and_belongs_to_many create a many to many relationship with the party that it connects. Therefore you can have two objects related to each other in this fashion:

issues.rb

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :labels
end
```

labels.rb

```
class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :issues
end
```

See section: 2.6 The has_and_belongs_to_many Association of this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

In the migration you create the join table, but you do not need to model it.

Now the way you are doing your create will always create a new label.

There is a difference in these two statements:

```
issue.labels.find_or_create_by(name: 'bug')
```

and

```
issue.labels << Label.find_or_create_by(name: 'bug')
```

The former looks inside the related labels to the issue and creates one if it doesn't exist. For instance, it only queries what issue.labels would return. Therefore when it can not find a related label to the issue with that name, it creates one. Now the latter query does this differently. It looks within the Labels model and says "is there any labels in here with the name 'bug'?" if there are, it finds that label and associates that a label of the issue. If not, it creates a new label before associating it with the issue.

In your case, the latter method will return the result you are looking for.

---- Sub question from Comments about deleting -----

has_and_belongs_to relationships are a 3 table join. When you call:

```
issue.labels.first
```

You are listing the first object within the labels collection. This object is a Label, not a join. Removing this, removes the actual object Label that is references in your join table.

```
issue.labels.first.delete
issue.labels.first.destroy
```

Both of these are equivalent to calling, assuming there was only one label in your collection (both remove the object, destroy triggers the callbacks):

```
Label.first.delete
Label.first.destroy
```

This is not what you are trying to achieve. What you need to do is call is this:

```
label = Label.first
issue.labels.delete(label)
```

This leaves the label as is, and just removes the association from the join table.

Comment: How does that work for removing them? When I call `issue.labels.first.delete` it deletes the association AND the entry in the Labels table, I only want it to delete the association in the join table.

Comment: I have updated the above to show you how & why this is the case